# xcode duplicates in arrray

Tags: iphone, xcode, arrays, nsarray

I have a NSArray with some "towns" in it (get these towns from a json database), but there are some towns 2 or 3 times in the array and I have to delete these towns.

How can I solve this problem? with a for-loop or a spezific function in x-code?

please help!

Comment: How would we know?  You haven't shown us any code or told us anything that help us assess the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one line solution, you need to add autorelease for non-ARC project

```
NSArray *array = // your array
NSArray filteredArray = [[[NSOrderedSet alloc] initWithArray:array] array];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all your towns and only add it to "uniqueItems" if it does not already exist inside of it

```
//Towns is an array of strings in this case

NSMutableArray *uniqueItems = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *town in towns)
    if (![uniqueItems containsObject:town])
        [uniqueItems addObject:town];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your array to an NSSet which can hold unique values only.

```
NSArray *array = ... // Your array of "towns"
NSSet *set = [[NSSet alloc] initWithArray:array];
NSArray *unique = [set allObjects];
```

If you're using a custom data class makse sure to implement `isEqual:`

Comment: there is an error:
no visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'allObjects'

Comment: Because you shouldd call allObjects on the NSSet object! Just copy/paste the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the procedure to do that,

```
NSArray *to = // your towns;
NSSet *set = [[NSSet alloc]initWithArray:towns];
arryl = [set allObjects];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `valueForKey` method for this.
that means you can create one NSSet of your arrays & then as per key you can get value

```
NSSet *uniqueStates = [NSSet setWithArray:[myArrayOfCustomObjects valueForKey:@"state"]];
```